# Error in Jquery code

Tags: jquery, json

I m unable to solve the unknown error coming in below code, page going blank.
valves are coming in obj. Please help.

```
function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    if (DataType == "json") {
        //alert(result);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
        if (obj != null) {

            $("#CoverFlow").html("<div id=contentFlow class=ContentFlow> " +
                "<div class=loadIndicator><div class=indicator></div></div> " +
                "<div class=flow>"
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {

                "  <div class=item href=#>   " +
                    "  <img id=" + value.ManufID + " class=content src=" + value.ManufUrl + " name=" + value.ManufName + " />" +
                    "  <div class=caption>" + value.ManufName + "  </div>" +
                    "  </div>"

            });
            "  </div>" +
                "  <div class=\"globalCaption\"></div>" +
                "  <div class=\"scrollbar\">" +
                "  <div class=\"slider\"><div class=\"position\"></div></div>" +
                "  </div>"

            "  </div> ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even with indentation, your code is unreadable, GL

Comment: please use jsfiddle.net to show a sample of the working... post the link here and we can get a better understanding of whats happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

although I didnt try running your code, but the issue (i think) seems to be in the orginzation of the code.

```
var coverFlowHTML="<div id=contentFlow class=ContentFlow> " +
                "<div class=loadIndicator><div class=indicator></div></div> " +
                "<div class=flow>";


            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {

                coverFlowHTML+="  <div class=item href=#>   " +
                    "  <img id=" + value.ManufID + " class=content src=" + value.ManufUrl + " name=" + value.ManufName + " />" +
                    "  <div class=caption>" + value.ManufName + "  </div>" +
                    "  </div>";

            });

            coverFlowHTML+="  </div>" +
                "  <div class=\"globalCaption\"></div>" +
                "  <div class=\"scrollbar\">" +
                "  <div class=\"slider\"><div class=\"position\"></div></div>" +
                "  </div>"

            "  </div> ");


$("#CoverFlow").html(coverFlowHTML);
```

I know this code can ( and needs very badly ) to be optimized, but this should give some results.

Comment: IMHO, IE is not exactly a browser, its a nightmare which is there to haunt and plague the world of Web development ;) .. please check the error console and place the results in your question, we can look into  it from there...

Answer (score 0):

Code really not very clear but is there a missing concatenation `+` operator?

```
        $("#CoverFlow").html("<div id=contentFlow class=ContentFlow> " +
            "<div class=loadIndicator><div class=indicator></div></div> " +
            "<div class=flow>" // <-- Missing operator??
        $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
```

What is the exact error you see?

Comment: i m not getting any error as it is jquery :) even when i added + operator there it is not working